# most streamlined approach for returning jsx from basic ts file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to encapsulate/delegate some configuration for a custom Grid in a separate TypeScript class.  The JavaScript object configurations are easy to split out into the separate class.  However, I'd also like to return some jsx from that TypeScript file.  What would be the most streamlined way to go about doing this?  Let's say that I've created a ts file named GridConfig.ts with the following implementation:

```
import JSX from 'react';

export class GridConfig {
    // what is the most lightweight implementation to return the jsx below?
    getSomeJsx() {
    return (
       <tr><td>TEST</td></tr>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler will do this for you.  There's a [page in the TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) on this.

Call your file GridConfig.tsx and in the compiler options (in tsconfig.json if you have one) set 'jsx' to 'react'.  You'll need to import React and ReactDOM in the tsx file.

The compiler will then turn your JSX into a React.createElement call, and TypeScript will think you are returning a type of JSX.Element.